# Split area under the curve into two halves

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Draw a vertical line say $x=t$ on curve $y= \sqrt{x}$ between $x=0$ and $x=a$ such that area under the curve from $x=0$ to $x=t$ equals area under the curve from $x=t$ to $x=a$.

I am looking for a generalized approach for other functions such as $y = \ln(x)$

Comment: What have you try? Do you know the integrals and how to integrate $ x \mapsto \sqrt x$?

Comment: Thanks @mathcounterexamples.net. I know integration but just somehow not able to frame the equation to integrate. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Find $t \in (0,a)$ such that

$$\int_0^t \sqrt x dx  = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^a \sqrt x dx.$$

Comment: Thanks @mathcounterexamples.net. Would it be more like: $\int_0^t {\sqrt x}dx = \int_t^a {\sqrt x}dx$ yielding equation $t^{\frac{3}{2}} = (a -t)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ to solve.

Comment: @Gerry Yes, you're right! I updated the hint. But you forgot the $1/2$ constant in your comment.

Comment: how to solve the equation $t^{\frac{3}{2}} = (a -t)^{\frac{3}{2}}$?

Comment: Raise both sides with the appropriate power!

Comment: $t^3 = (a -t)^3$ gives $2t^{3} - 3t^{2}a + 3a^2t - t^3  = 0$ to solve.

Comment: Raising both sides with power $2/3$ would ease your computations... But again you forgot the factor $1/2$!

Comment: t = a/2 cannot be the right answer

Comment: Please read carrefully... The correct equation is $t^{3/2} = \frac{1}{2} a^{3/2}$ from my hint. Or $t^{3/2} =  a^{3/2} - t^{3/2}$ which is about the same!

Comment: Thanks @mathcounterexamples.net I made a mistake. so the solution is $t=\frac{a}{4^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

Comment: That seems a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a non-negative function $f: [0,a]\to \mathbb{R}^+$, you need to compute $t \in (0,a)$ such that
$$
\int_0^t f(x)dx = \int_t^a f(x) dx
$$

The actual ability to have an exact value for $t$ depends on beeing able to compute a primitive of $f$.

Comment: Thanks @PierreCarre. How to solve the equation $t^{\frac{3}{2}} = (a -t)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ ?

Comment: @Gerry Square both sides! Also it's easier to consider $\left[\dfrac23 x\sqrt{x} \right]_0^t = \left[\dfrac23 x\sqrt{x} \right]_t^a $

Comment: Hence in this case $\dfrac23 t\sqrt{t} = \dfrac23 a\sqrt{a} - \dfrac23 t\sqrt{t} \implies 2t\sqrt{t} = a\sqrt{a} $. Now square both sides

Comment: Thanks @NεoPλατo so basically solution is $t=\frac{a}{4^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

Comment: Yep. Have fun doing that for $\ln x$

Answer (score 1):

More generally, you want to find $a$ such that

$$\int_0^a f(x)\,dx=\int_ a^t f(x)\,dx.$$

If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, this turns to

$$F(a)-F(0)=F(t)-F(a)$$

or the equation in $a$

$$F(a)=\frac{F(0)+F(t)}2,$$ or

$$a=F^{-1}\left(\frac{F(0)+F(t)}2\right).$$

With the square root function, this gives

$$a=\left(\frac32\frac{t\sqrt t}3\right)^{2/3}=2^{-2/3}t.$$

For an arbitrary exponent $u$,

$$2^{-1/(u+1)}t.$$

---

Unfortunately, the case of the logarithm is not tractable, as

$$\int\log t\,dt=t(\log t-1)$$ which cannot be inverted analytically.

---

For the exponential,

$$a=\log\left(\frac{1+e^t}2\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

You have function $y=f(x)$ for which you want to split area under the curve. Since you want area under the curve assume $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in(0,a)$.

The area to the left is
$$
\int_0^tf(x)dx
$$
increasing with $t$ and the area to the right is
$$
\int_t^a f(x)dx
$$
is decreasing with $t$. Evidently we have $0<t<a$. You want both areas equal,
first define $h(t)$ such that
$$
h(t)=\int_0^tf(x)dx-\int_t^a f(x)dx
$$
which is an increasing function. The areas are equal when $h(t)=0$ and you may find the root to $h(t)$ by the interval halving method.